# Charting lib open or commerical

Tags: javascript, mapping, data-visualization, vector-graphics

Anyone have advice on how to get a control to do something like this 
http://screencast.com/t/VyHdxOdRJQwY

I will be plotting based on city or zip so i need to maintain some geo aspects but in the end the chart control needs to look like this guy.

Ideally no flash... but interested to see if anyone has hit something like this.

open or commercial source, im game

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using http://www.mapdotnet.com/ with background from open maps. Custom middle cache tiles from shape files stored in SQL, on top we have open street layer (or can use bing)

Answer (score 0):

[d3](https://github.com/mbostock/d3) seems to be a pretty good library for data visualization.

Check out the examples here: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery

Here's an implementation similar to what you are looking for. http://trends.truliablog.com/vis/metro-movers/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check out the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/). There are two versions of the API:

- [Static Maps API V2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) - from the docs:

> The Google Static Maps API lets you embed a Google Maps image on your
>   web page without requiring JavaScript or any dynamic page loading. The
>   Google Static Map service creates your map based on URL parameters
>   sent through a standard HTTP request and returns the map as an image
>   you can display on your web page.

There are Usage Limits: The free version has a query limit of 1000 unique (different) image requests per viewer per day, if that will work for your situation. There is a licensed option above that with associated licensing fees.

- [Google Maps JavaScript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) - from the docs:

> The Google Maps Javascript API lets you embed Google Maps in your own
>   web pages. Version 3 of this API is especially designed to be faster
>   and more applicable to mobile devices, as well as traditional desktop
>   browser applications. The API provides a number of utilities for
>   manipulating maps (just like on the http://maps.google.com web page)
>   and adding content to the map through a variety of services, allowing
>   you to create robust maps applications on your website.

There are similar usage limits for this version, also with a licensed option above the free version.

The API could easily create a map to match the one at your link. These aren't an exact match, but here are some examples from the [Google Maps Demo Gallery](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/demogallery):

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]